# NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**PROJECT**NAME***/messages:send

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging" };
private GoogleCredentials googleCredentials;
private InputStream jasonfile;
private String beaerertoken;
private String BEARERTOKEN;
public static final String URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**PROJECT**HERE***/messages:send";
```

```
try {getAccessToken();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

CVnotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String fcmtitle = "wew";
                String fcmmsg = "mem";
                if(!fcmtitle.equals("") && !fcmmsg.equals("")){
                    pushNotificationo(
                            HomePage.this,
                            "***devicetoken***",
                            fcmtitle,
                            fcmmsg
                    );
                }
            }
        });
```

```
 private void getAccessToken() throws IOException {

    jasonfile = getResources().openRawResource(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("service_account", "raw", getPackageName()));


        new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                        .fromStream(jasonfile)
                        .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));

                googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();

                beaerertoken = googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken().getTokenValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "beaerertoken:  " + beaerertoken);

                BEARERTOKEN = beaerertoken;

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d(TAG, "In error statement");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }).start();
    }
```

`public void pushNotificationo(Context context, String devicetoken, String fcmtitle, String fcmmsg){

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("token", devicetoken);
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("title", fcmtitle);
        notification.put("body", fcmmsg);
        json.put("notification", notification);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_CONFIG.URL_FCM, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                System.out.println("FCM " + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //System.out.println("FAILURE " + error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
                params.put("Authorization", " Bearer "+ BEARERTOKEN);
                return params;
            }
        };

        homeReqQue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}`
```

THe Error that I am getting:

```
[6711] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/***PROJECT**HERE***/messages:send
```

Hello, I am trying to push notification from an android device to another with Firebase Cloud Messaging http v1. However, I getting this Unexpected response code 400 error. Do I miss something important in the code? Can someone help me out here?